# Python: Reading an Access database that contains ODBC linked tables

Tags: python, sql, database, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to read an Access query in pandas, but run into the following error. Could anyone kindly assist?

My code seems to work if I convert the ODBC tables to local tables in Access (but I rather not do this). Also, I already tried turning off pooling and it didn't help.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

pyodbc.pooling = False

connStr = (
    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"Dbq=C:/users/myname/Documents/database.accdb;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM query",conn)
```

Here's the error:

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM query': ('HY000', "[HY000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] ODBC--connection to 'SQL
>   Server' failed. (-2001) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Can we assume that you are not prompted for login credentials when you try to open the tables in Access itself?

Comment: Also, what is the ODBC driver name and version that the linked tables are using?

Comment: For the ODBC tables, I'm using trusted connection, driver = SQL Server, and APP=Microsoft Office 2013 (if this is what you mean by version).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using the old "SQL Server" ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.DLL version 6.01.7601.17514). Can you post a download link for a sample database that includes the query you are trying to run and the tables+links on which it depends? (Local tables can be empty, and table links will have a .Connect property that can be used to reconstruct the SQL Server backend.)

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#databases-containing-odbc-linked-tables):

> pyodbc can work with Access databases that contain ODBC Linked Tables if we disable connection pooling before connecting to the Access database

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling = False
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ= ... ")
```

Comment: But OP has that line in posted (unedited) code `pyodbc.pooling = False`.